# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when building nspredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate, exc-bad-access

I am calculating the number of months between a birthdate and today.
With that number, I am building a predicate to fetch objects from core data.
Although the number of months is calculated correctly (as the log shows), I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when building the predicate.

Here is my code:

```
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:birthdate
                                              toDate:today options:0];
    int months = [components month];
    NSLog(@"months: %ld", (long)months);
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(alter_min_monat > %@)", months];
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `%@` with a `int`? Try with `%d` instead.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The issue is the placeholder, not with `NSPredicate` directly, but with `initWithFormat:` that is innerly called.

`%@` shouldn't be used with an `int`, use `%d` instead.

So this line:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(alter_min_monat > %@)", months];
```

Should be:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(alter_min_monat > %d)", months];
```

Other linked information : [String Programming Guide: String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)