# NSPredicate in swift for empty string

Tags: swift, nspredicate

Swift 4.2 iOS 11.x

Trying to read the records in a iCloud database that have a lineOwner field set, but struggling to create an NSPredicate that works!

This looks ok, but doesn't parse.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: remoteAttributes.lineOwner + " != %@",0)
```

I get an invalid predicate error message [and a nasty crash into the bargain]. Spend a couple of hours on this and losing the will to live.

If I print out the database I see this.

[image]

Comment: The crash is because you are having a placeholder `%@` but use an `Int` instead. Use a String (`""`) and not `0`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610509/exc-bad-access-when-building-nspredicate/27566124#27566124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply compare to the empty `String`, `""`. The `%@` placeholder represents a `String`, so the crash happens because you supply an `Int` to the `NSPredicate` instead of a `String`.

You should also use the `%K` placeholder for variable names instead of appending strings.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: " %K != %@", remoteAttributes.lineOwner, "")
```

If you also want to filter out `nil` values, you can use a compound predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: " %K != %@ AND %K != nil", remoteAttributes.lineOwner, "")
```

Comment: The crash shouldn't appear because of/during the comparison, but rather in the construction of the `NSPredicate`, through the `String(format:)` because of a mismatch between the placeholder and the value for it.

Comment: This works, at least compiles and doesn't crash. The value I am getting back is a nil, not an empty string it seems. Tried substituting NULL and nil, neither work.

Comment: @user3069232 check my updated answer, that filters out `nil` values as well

Comment: Sorry David, that produces a runtime crash! With this error message -[__NSCFNumber rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbadd2041a6bcbead

Comment: @user3069232 are you sure `remoteAttributes.lineOwner` is `Optional` and can actually be `nil`?

Comment: I edited the question, and printed out the contents of the iCloud database. So I want the records with a lineOwnerfield only.

Comment: @user3069232 could you also add the definition of your class so that I can see against what data (type) should the predicate actually filter?

Comment: `-[__NSCFNumber rangeOfString:]: ` Wait. What is `remoteAttributes.lineOwner` exactly? Is a Number? It should be a `String` indicating the KeyPath of your object attributes. Could you show update your model in your question?

Comment: It is defined as a String, and as you can see in one of the values is set to "Yahoo". I want the record with "Yahoo" and I don't want the other one.

Comment: No, the value to construct the predicate. It has to be a String, your are misunderstanding how is constructed a `NSPredicate`. The first part is a key path, not a value. From the log, replace `remoteAttributes.lineOwner` with `"lineOwner"`.

Comment: I got this to work by making sure lineOwner field is created; and than use the original "" format suggested! THANKS guys!!