# NSPredicate | Gives bad exception on Entity Fetch Request | Swift 4

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I try to get an Entity via an NSPredicate from CoreData model. Initially I insert an entity using its `id` and now intend to get it. However my code crashes without any further description on specifically my `NSPredicate`. I have no idea why? My `id` attribute is `Int32`:

```
        var employTime:EmployeeTime?
        let context = getContext()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "EmployeeTime")

        //code crashes on this bottom line
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let employTimes = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [EmployeeTime]
        if (employTimes?.count)! > 0 {
            for et in employTimes! {
                if et.id == id {
                    employTime = et
                }
            }
        } else {
            employTime = EmployeeTime(context: context)
        }
        return employTime!
```

Any help most greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS when building nspredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610509/exc-bad-access-when-building-nspredicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common mistake.

The placeholder `%@` is only for objects, for an `Int32` you need `%d` or `%i`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d", id)
```

And create the fetch request with the concrete `NSManagedObject` subclass

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<EmployeeTime>(entityName: "EmployeeTime")
```

this avoids the type cast later.

---

Your entire code can be simplified (no optionals needed):

```
let employTime:EmployeeTime
let context = getContext()
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<EmployeeTime>(entityName: "EmployeeTime")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d", id)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
let employTimes = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
if let et = employTimes.first {
   employTime = et
} else {
   employTime = EmployeeTime(context: context)
}
return employTime
```

However you should avoid `try!`. Make your function `throw` and hand over a potential error to the caller.

Comment: Wohoo! Works like a charm :) Thank you for all the tips as well.

Comment: can you however tell me if predicate should be = or == and what is the difference between them

Comment: There is no difference, please see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html