# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when using NSLog on Swift Enum in Objective C code

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, enums

I am getting a crash `Thread 21: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x101e)` when trying to log a Swift enum in my Objective C code.

Enum passed in as the result of a completion handler on Swift function call from Obj C code:

```
 NSLog(@"Completed with operation: %@", operation);
```

Enum:

```
@objc public enum Operation: Int {
    case Unknown
    case Operation1
    case Operation2
    case Operation1And2
}
```

I tired the following 2 variations and the app failed to build. There is an issue with Xcode that prevents me from being able to see what the actual error was.

```
 NSLog(@"Completed with operation: %@", [operation description]);

 NSLog(@"Completed with operation: %@", [operation value]);
```

I want to do basic operation on this enum like log its value, do boolean comparisons. But I am a little lost on how to do that as fairly new to Objective C.

Comment: If it's an Int, you should use `%d`, not `%@`, that's why. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1 It's the same reason : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610509/exc-bad-access-when-building-nspredicate/27566124#27566124

Comment: Got it and how would I do boolean comparisons on it? I am getting `error: receiver type 'Operation' (aka 'enum Operation') is not an Objective-C class` when doing `if (operation == [Operation Operation1])`

Comment: `if (operation == OperationOperation1) {}`

Comment: Thanks that built. Last question, is it possible to NSLog  the string `OperationOperation1`. Using %d gave me an unhelpful `897745528` as output.

Comment: No, you need to add an extra method to transform the Int value into String...

Comment: But why is the int value not equal to 0, 1, 2? Why is it such a long number?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094984/convert-objective-c-typedef-to-its-string-equivalent to print it.